# copy pasting text in other languages from pdf

Tags: 12.04, pdf, unicode

Here is a [pdf](http://downloads.ziddu.com/download/21643007/Sai-Charitra_-_www.apnihindi.com.pdf.html/eng)

I want to copy paste a few paragraphs
and email to some friend
I am on Ubuntu 12.04 (can not upgrade at this moment)
when I copy paste then I get following

```
[Lra~g66Q3⁄4[Q3⁄4Q3⁄40wÀ~[OrÃv¿9(·©9©g(·~Q3⁄4NM©s(©·|Lv¿­v¿ [(©·~sQ3⁄4L
Ã®­v¿9©oLs90
```

How can I improve this situation I am not able to email text.
Neither copy pasting in libreoffice works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said here: https://forums.adobe.com/message/3978297
It seems this is either a corrupted file issue or an intentional copy protection method, and there is no easy way to repair it. The suggested solution is to perform an OCR of the file in order to correct the errors and generate a new file.

I suggest downloading it again if possible.

The way to OCR the file is stated here: https://forums.adobe.com/message/3938668#3938668#3938668